# zip file get corrupted when uploaded to an express server

Tags: node.js, express, file, http, multer

I am making a system to transfer files btween two nodejs aplications in two different servers. But I am having a problem, when the file is uploaded to http request and received in the express server ( with multer ) the .zip file gets corrupted. Can any one help me?

**Server - 1**

```
zipDirectory(
  `C:/Users/${config.usuario}/Backup/`,
  `C:/Users/${config.usuario}/backup.zip`
);
var nbackup = uuidv4();
const form = new FormData();
const file = fs.readFile(
  `C:/Users/${config.usuario}/backup.zip`,
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    form.append(
      "arquivo",
      fs.createReadStream(`C:/Users/${config.usuario}/backup.zip`)
    );
    axios
      .post(
        `${config.api}/backup?chave=${process.env.CHAVE}&vps=${config.vps}&id=${nbackup}`,
        form,
        {
          headers: {
            ...form.getHeaders()
          }
        }
      )
      .then((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (res.status == 200) {
          fs.unlinkSync(`C:/Users/${config.usuario}/backup.zip`);
          fs.unlinkSync(`C:/Users/${config.usuario}/Backup`);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
);
```

**Server - 2**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Extração da extensão do arquivo original:
    const extensaoArquivo = file.originalname.split(".")[1];

    // Cria um código randômico que será o nome do arquivo
    const novoNomeArquivo = require("crypto").randomBytes(64).toString("hex");

    // Indica o novo nome do arquivo:
    cb(null, `${novoNomeArquivo}.${extensaoArquivo}`);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/api/backup", upload.single("arquivo"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("DOWNLOADING FILE");
});
```

**OPENING THE ZIP ON SERVER 1: ( TRANSLATED FROM PORTUGUESE )**

Windows cannot open this folder

Compressed folder is invalid

name_of_the_file.zip is invalid

[image]

**OPENING THE ZIP ON SERVER 2**

[image]